# Side length of a particular quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Reference image:

[image]

I just need to find $d$ as a function of $a$ and $b$, with the knowledge that $c$ is twice the length of $d$. I've been staring at this problem for much longer than I'd like to admit and have filled up almost $2$ full sheets of paper with work for what I'm fairly sure should be a simple problem. I'm going to sleep on it now, but if anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: you can form a right triangle whose legs are $a$ and $b-d$, and whose hypotenuse is $c$. You also know that $c = 2d$.

Comment: This type of quadrilateral is called a right trapezoid.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by Pythagoras' Theorem,

\begin{align*}
  a^2+(b-d)^2 &= c^2 \\
  a^2+(b-d)^2 &= 4d^2 \\
  3d^2+2bd-a^2-b^2 &= 0 \\
  d &= \frac{-2b+\sqrt{(2b)^2+4(3)(a^2+b^2)}}{2(3)} \\
  &= \frac{-b+\sqrt{3a^2+4b^2}}{3} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If we make $NH$ perpendicular to $PQ$ we will have a rectangle $MNQH$ and then

$$MN=QH=d \quad \text{and} \quad MQ=NH=a$$

After that we conclude that

$$HP=b-d$$

because $QP=b$. Now doing Pythagoras' theorem at the triangle $NHP$ we have:

$$c^2=a^2+(b-d)^2$$

but $c=2d$ so the last equation became:

$$(2d)^2=a^2+(b-d)^2$$

$$4d^2=a^2+b^2-2bd+d^2$$

$$3d^2+2bd-a^2-b^2=0$$

$$d=\frac{-2b\pm \sqrt{12a^2+16b^2}}{6}=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{3a^2+4b^2}}{3}$$

but once $d>0$ then

$$d=\frac{-b+ \sqrt{3a^2+4b^2}}{3}$$